# Why is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} x^{1/x}=0?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Why is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} x^{1/x}=0?$

I believe it is from graphing it, but I'm not able to prove it.  Log w/ L'Hospitals isn't working for me since ln(x)/x isn't the right indeterminant form.

Comment: Hint: $ln(x)/x$ is not indeterminate, at $0$ it is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^{1/x} = e^{\ln x / x}$ so indeed all you need to show is that $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln x / x = -\infty$, which you can do without L'hopital's rule, just simply by noting that $\ln x \to -\infty$ and $1/x \to +\infty$ as you approach $0$ from the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{\;\,x\to0^+}x^{1/x}=\lim_{\,y\to\infty}\frac1{y^y}$$.

R.H.S. is certainly $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, it seems they replaced $x$ with $1/x$, so that $x \to 0^+$ becomes $x \to \infty$.

Comment: If $y=1/x$, then $x^{1/x}=(1/y)^y=1/(y^y)$, but $y\to\infty$ if $x\to0^+$.

Comment: Sorry. I glanced too quickly and missed the limit. My apologies. May I suggest, however, that it's good to use a different letter when you make the substitution? That way readers are forced to think a bit more than I evidently did.